# gradle error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava' " while build groovy in android studio

Tags: groovy, build, gradle, android-studio

I got a error while building groovy code in android studio.
the error msg is

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lytest110\app\src\main\java\gzzhe\com\lytest110\MainActivity.java:41: error: can't find symbol
        Log.d("lytest110", GroovyTest.getMsg());
                           ^
  symbol:   parameter GroovyTest
  possition: class MainActivity
1 error

 FAILED
:app:compileDebugGroovy

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

my build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
        classpath 'me.champeau.gradle:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

the build.gradle in app directory:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.champeau.gradle.groovy-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gzzhe.com.lytest110"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/groovy-2.4.0-beta-3-grooid.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

1. I have put the groovy file into main/groovy/package/name directory.
2. the groovy is annotated with @CompileStatic.

This problem have puzzled me for several days.

Answer (score 0):

From your error it seems like you are calling Groovy class with Java. According to the Android Groovy plugin readme. it says

`Groovy sources must be found inside src/main/groovy. Note that the plugin follows the behavior of the Groovy plugin in Gradle, which means that if you want to be able to have Groovy classes referencing Java classes that themselves reference Groovy classes, then those Java classes must be found inside src/main/groovy too (this is called joint compilation).`

So you just put your MainActivity.java to your ../main/groovy/package/name directory